# Why empty object is valid for non exact type annotation in flow type?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I mean code like

```
const someObj: { id: number } = {};
const num: number = someObj.id;
console.log(num);
```

`num` here is undefined, and definitely not a number

Snippet can be checked here
https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoAxnAdgZwC5g5wC2ApgPIBGAVgFxgDeYAlgCb1YCuxlpATmAC+YALyNBAbgzZ8YLsQ7deAsUTJVqAOjYSgA

Comment: Related https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/8214#issuecomment-562284047

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [documented limitation](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/objects/#toc-unknown-property-lookup-on-unsealed-objects-is-unsafe) for unsealed objects:

> Unsealed objects allow new properties to be written at any time. Flow ensures that reads are compatible with writes, but does not ensure that writes happen before reads (in the order of execution).

> This means that reads from unsealed objects with no matching writes are never checked. This is an unsafe behavior of Flow which may be improved in the future.

So normally flow can check that `id` is written as number, but can not check if `id` has actually been written to the `someObj`.

Comment: The question is specifically about non exact types.. And this is not related to sealed/unsealed as type is specified explicitly and not inferred

Comment: @AlekseyL. I'm just saying how flow works (objects are inexact by default), and why this particular example is valid for flow. If you see a better answer - go ahead, post it ;)

Comment: If object would be unsealed, `someObj.foo = 'foo';` would be allowed. But it is not https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoAxnAdgZwC5g5wC2ApgPIBGAVgFxgDeYAlgCb1YCuxlpATmAC+YALyNBAblREyVagDo2osACYJYYMDDkA1tJIUa8qHDjKA5CbjmJQA So how sealed/unsealed is related to the question?

Comment: Looks like a bug with empty object literals https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/8214#issuecomment-562284047

Comment: yeah, it seems to better not to use unsealed object: [This means that reads from unsealed objects with no matching writes are never checked.](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/objects/#toc-unknown-property-lookup-on-unsealed-objects-is-unsafe) @AlekseyL.

Comment: @AlekseyL., idk why `foo` is not allowed to be written, perhaps b/c of different behaviour when unsealed object is typed (doc considers unsealed objects with no types). Updated answer, thanks!

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense (still weird behavior )

Comment: @Alex Thanks for your answer/discussion, it helps to understand what is going on here :) FIY - I also created an issue - https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/8430

Answer (score 0):

Added an issue, there is some discussion about too - https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/8430